# systemd $HOME environment variable different from expected

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, root, home

I have a service that runs as root:

```
[Unit]
Description=my service
After=docker.service network-online.target
Requires=docker.service network-online.target

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=60
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=/usr/bin/myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am getting some unexpected behavior with this:

The environment variable `$HOME` is set to `/root` when I look at the environment variable that `myservice` is getting which is causing it to fail.

However, as the root user I am getting:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/root
```

This is in line with what I see in `/etc/passwd`

```
root:x:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/sh
```

When I run `myservice` manually, it gets the correct `$HOME` env variable and it works.

I would like `$HOME` to be `/home/root`, not `/root`. So...

1. Where is `systemd` getting `/root` from, and why is `$HOME` getting overwritten?
2. How do I prevent `systemd` from doing this globally, aside from explicitly setting the `$HOME` environment variable in the service file? <-- upon reviewing the source code this doesn't seem like it'll make a difference

Comment: What Unix are you on where the root home directory is placed under `/home`?

Comment: Yocto, which by default places root's home directory under /home. We can change this or even symlink /root to /home/root but I am still curious about how `systemd` handles cases where root has a non standard home directory

Answer (score 5):

After examining the source code, I found out `systemd` actually hardcodes the `home` directory for `root` users. I have not found any documentation on configs that can change this so it's just something to be aware of for Yocto projects using the default home directory.

I confirmed this by modifying the hard coded `/root` values to `/home/root` in https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/basic/user-util.c and observed the modified `systemd` was spawning services with the correct `$HOME` variable.

As of now, symlinking `/root` with `/home/root` is a good workaround. Switching the default `ROOT_HOME` to `/root` may not be a bad idea to be [consistent with the rest of the linux world](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/poky/2014-July/009821.html).

Comment: They also appear to have a reason for it stated in the source code comments: "/* We enforce some special rules for uid=0 and uid=65534: in order to avoid NSS lookups for root we hardcode their user record data. */" That seems to make some sense, esp. considering that some services might need to be up for the NSS lookups to work, etc...

Comment: Kudos for the fault finding - and for sharing the outcome here. You should be posting a bug to YoctoProject.